# How to traverse a folder path in PHP?

Tags: php

Note: I am always confused about path traversing.

I have a root folder.

I have a php file which is in this location.

```
root/plupload/examples/upload.php
```

Now, I have a folder which is like this:-

```
root/uploads
```

In the upload.php, I have a code which is to create a folder called `post_video` under the folder `uploads`.

The script is like this:-

```
$targetDir = '../../uploads/post_videos/';
$cleanupTargetDir = true; // Remove old files
$maxFileAge = 5 * 3600; // Temp file age in seconds

if(!is_dir($targetDir)) { 
            mkdir($targetDir , 0777);
            chmod($targetDir , 0777);
}
```

The folder isn't getting created. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried it with file_exists() instead of is_dir ??? and in mkdir make it like mkdir($targetDir , 0777, true);

Comment: Tried all. @Bhavin. I think the path has the problem.

Comment: are you working on local or live  ??
Is there any .htaccess file which is making problem ? have you tried with other folder name ?

Comment: Have you got permission to create the folder where you are trying to create it? You should get a warning about that according to [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)

Comment: Try with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/post_videos/'` or `__DIR__.'/../../uploads/post_videos/'`